# Firebug - Automatic Refresh for Watched Variables?

Tags: firebug

Is it possible to automatically refresh the value of variables put on `watch` in Firebug? (Right now, it seems I have to right click the variable in the Watch variable and select refresh..)

Answer (score 1):

The 'watch' expressions are reevaluated every time you hit a breakpoint or single step.